# how to send ajax post request to asp and save received data to .json file

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, asp-classic

I'm sending ajax post request to .asp file on server and want to save result to data.json file on the server

my javascript/jquery:

```
data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
message['data'] = data;
$.post('./data/data.asp', message)
```

my asp:

```
dim fs,f,ts,data
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("/data/data.json"),2,true)
data = Request.QueryString("data")
f.Write(data)
f.Close
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You jQuery code is using a POST request to submit the data. 
Try reading the forms collection

```
data = Request.Form("data")
```

Comment: are you sure, the post is actually calling your data/data.asp page? Do you receive a 200 OK from the web server? If you are using IE you can check the network traffic using F12 tools.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following with IE, Chorme and FF and the data is always in the Form collection. The code should be stored as 36661267.asp and will call itself with the POST data, and display the data directly after the body tag.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<% option explicit %>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<%
  Response.Write(Request.Form( "data"))
%>



<a href="#" id="clickMe">click me</a>
<br />
 <textarea id="res" rows="40" cols="60">
  </textarea>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#clickMe").on( "click", function( e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = JSON.stringify({"field1": "value1"}, null, 2);
        var message = {};
        message['data'] = data;
        $.post('36661267.asp', message, function(response) {
          $("#res").text(response);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So i figured this out. Problem was with output file itself (for some reason i could read data from .json file with ajax but couldnt make changes). I have created file thought "createTextFile" and saved my data there and now i'm able to read data with ajax and to rewrite data with asp. Thanks